# Flutter remove spaces and line breaks in string between character pattern

Tags: xml, string, flutter, dart

I have some xml that I need to be converted into a string with no spaces between the characters > and  <

for example I have:

```
     <w:body>
          <w:p w14:paraId="177B7ABA" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00405720" w:rsidRDefault="00405720" w:rsidP="004A7B99">
                 <w:pPr>
                        <w:ind w:right="-11"></w:ind>
                        <w:rPr>
```

What I need to convert it to:

```
<w:body><w:p w14:paraId="177B7ABA" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00405720" w:rsidRDefault="00405720" w:rsidP="004A7B99"><w:pPr><w:ind w:right="-11"></w:ind><w:rPr>
```

I have tried regexExp:

```
 debugPrint (documentXML.replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ''),
```

But that that removes all of the spaces even within the elemennts and then when I try to do replace '\n' for the line breaks after doing that I cuts off the string.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the following RegExp instead:

```dart
documentXml.replaceAll(RegExp(' {2,}'), ' ')
```

This replaces two or more whitespace with a single whitespace.